# crop triangle from blackbackground

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to *image processing and development*.I have a triangle in black background. I want to save that triangle as a Mat object without black pixels[0]. In order to do I tried as below.

1. Set threshold
2. find contours
3. identify contour[0] as trangle // has 2 contours one is triangle other one is backpixels.
4. save the contour points
5. crop the image.

My code please find below.

```
 Mat finalImage = imread("test.png, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        img.copyTo(finalImage, mask);

        Mat canny_output;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        int thresh = 100;
        int max_thresh = 255;
        RNG rng(12345);

        /// Detect edges using canny
        Canny(finalImage, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);
        /// Find contours
        findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0)); //find this method

        /// Draw contours
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(canny_output.size(), CV_8UC1);
        for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
            drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point()); // find this method.
        }
```

I have points of contour but by using points of contours i have no idea how to crop only the trangle **in input image**.

[image]

Comment: You already asked this question a few times. What isn't clear about the fact the 1) the image **must be rectangular**, so you can't have a triangular image? 2) in the rectangular image, you can use the **alpha channel as a mask**, for example setting to transparent all pixels outside the triangle?

Comment: Miki is right, Image can not be triangular. Please elaborate what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bounding Rect of the various contours at the same time you are re drawing the contours. So in Your for loop where you are iterating the contours, you may use [`cv::boundingRect()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) to get the bounding Rect of the respective contour as:

```
/// Draw contours
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(canny_output.size(), CV_8UC1);
for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point()); // find this method.
        cv::Rect boundingRect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
    }
```

Comment: but this method gives triangle inside rectangle. The rectangle has blackpixels. I want to isolate only triangle

Comment: Please attach expected output then .